# Correct way to add 22 to 4 to get 9999

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[Inspired](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-given-value) [by](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-82) [four](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33366/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-70) [other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33420/correct-way-to-add-22-to-4-to-get-613867) puzzles, how could it be possible that adding 22 to 4 gives 9999? What is the correct way to do it?

As with all of the other puzzles, consider these numbers in base 10.

Comment: Base 10 as in base $1010_2$?

Comment: Yes, and as in the number of periods ending that sentence if you prefer..........

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it is a low-quality question, probably with no definite answer. See [the meta discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4928/13191)

Comment: @ev3commander why don't you just use the roman numeral X, and not make the representation of numbers so complicated?

Answer (score 11):

Just a stab at this. Probably not the answer by a long shot, but might be interesting.

> Read "22 to 4" as "Two two to four", which can be also $2$ to $24$. Adding up the numbers from $2$ to $24$ give $299$. Two $99$s concatenated give $9999$.

Answer (score 3):

In the additive cyclic group of integers modulo $9973$ $(\mathbb Z_{9973})$:

> $\overline{22}+\overline{4 }=\overline{22+4}=\overline{26}= \overline{9973+26}=\overline{9999}$, where $\overline x$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$.

Comment: This could literally be used for any integer 27 or greater. To add 22+4 to get $n$, simply consider operating in $\mathbb{Z}_{n-26}$.

Comment: @JoeZ. this method can be used for _any_ integer in $\mathbb Z_{|n-26|}$.